# What is the role of information matrix in Likelihood estimation?

Tags: estimation, econometrics, fisher-information

I couldn't grasp what it refers to exactly so I would like to understand how we use it:

from MLE, Score Vector is:

$$
S(\theta;y) = \frac{\partial l(\theta;y) }{\partial \theta}
$$

$l$ comes from the **log** version of the likelihood function and this score vector has an asymptotic distribution with Information Matrix which is:

$$
I(\theta) = -E\left(\frac{\partial l(\theta;y) }{\partial \theta \partial \theta ^T } \right)
$$

I appreciate it if you can explain how to use it and which sources I can use.

Comment: There are so many posts pertaining to Information matrix [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Information+matrix). What exactly do you need?

Comment: I just can't understand what we did by taking this differentiation.  But I guess it is related to the Variance of the Score vector

Comment: Hi: Below is a good  introduction with possibly good references. https://andrewliao11.github.io/blog/fisher-info-matrix/

Comment: Maybe this can help:  [What kind of information is Fisher information?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/196576/what-kind-of-information-is-fisher-information/197471#197471)

Comment: Thanks for your recommendations, I will check them.

Comment: @Tatanik501 after reading them, you can update your post if you have any possible confusion (s) left.

Comment: Thank you sir, the first one is a quite impressive and smooth explanation.